# Try filename.js.php if filename.js is missing NGINX rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I would like the to rewrite any filename.js request to filename.js.php for any .js in any folder on the server.  I am trying this:

```
location ~ ^/(.)$\.js {
try_files $uri $uri.php;
}
```

So.

```
myserver.com/somepath/filename.js
```

rewrites if the file is missing to:

```
myserver.com/somepath/filename.js.php
```

Comment: Try learning a bit more about regular expressions before trying to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this location for your task (place it before php location):

```
location ~ \.js$ {
   try_files $uri $uri.php;
}
```